# Is ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean a distributed cache?

Tags: java, spring

I wasn't able to identify if ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean would provide a distributed cache. Intuition says no because the docs mentioned "used *within **a*** Spring container" but I would like to confirm because the configuration for it seems to be the simplest!

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/concurrent/ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean.html

FYI I have the following bean in my xml

```
    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager">
        <property name="caches">
            <set>
                <bean
                        class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean"
                        name="testCache"/>
            </set>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: No, it's definitely not a distributed cache. ConcurrentMapCache docs says; `Simple Cache implementation based on the core JDK java.util.concurrent package. Useful for testing or simple caching scenarios`

Comment: If you want distributed caching, look for Hazelcast, Memcached, Redis, Aerospike, ...